# Is Google AMP supported in Thailand / for Thai language?

Tags: amp-html, notsupportedexception, thai, google-amp, accelerated-mobile-page

During a visit to Google Headquarter in Bangkok, we learned that Thailand was the only country not supporting AMP. (more specifically Thai language as English pages works just fine).

As this meeting was last March, I was just wondering if it's still accurate ? (and hopping that it's not).

For now we are going to develop in PWA, but I would like to go beyond and create an AMPWA 8).

I couldn't find any documentation around that issue so any information is welcomed.

Thank you,

Comment: If you're referring to translations of AMP documentation in Thai language, you may check the upper right corner of this [page](https://www.ampproject.org/).

Comment: No, to the AMP itself. Someone from Google told us that AMP was not functioning in Thailand. If i'm not mistaken it's because of the thai language

Comment: To give an example, on a previous product the AMP symbol is going to appear on google search next to the pages in English. But none of the Thai pages will have it. Seeing the difference between the loading speed, AMP doesn't seems to work on pages in Thai language as said by the Google Thailand manager.